# "Hide" column from database, but not View in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I am using a code-first methodology. I have created my own user model and membership provider.  My model has some of the following fields:

```
[Table("mytable")]
public class MyUser
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; } // Auto generated

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Your name/company name")] 
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that I don't have a `ConfirmPassword` column in my database (for obvious reasons). How do I "hide" this from the database, but allow the view to be able to see an use it. Changing it to `private` hides it from the database, but the view doesn't like that.

How can I tell Entity Framework to ignore this field?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mark the column you don't want to persist to database with `[NotMapped]` attribute.

Btw. this is typical example where you should think about differing between persisted entity and view model for your page = you should think about having two different classes.

Comment: While this did work... it didn't in the implementation. The data model was still trying to validate the two fields (even after I encrypt the password). I ended up having two models. One for the DB, one for the view.

Comment: If you share the model between EF and UI you must turn off validation in EF.