# How to register UserModel using EntityFramework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

In My Model there is 4 field

```
[Table("MUser")]
public class UserModel
{
  [Required]
  [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
  [Key, Column("ID", TypeName = "uniqueidentifier")]
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string UserName {get; set;}
  [Required]
  [Column("Password", TypeName = "nvarchar")]
  public string Password {get; set;}
  [Required]
  [DataType(DataType.Password)]
  [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
  [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage ="The password and conf password do not match.")]
  public string ConfirmPassword {get; set;}
}
```

**Note:** ConfirmPassword is not part of the database field

So when try to save

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ActionName("UserRegister")]
public ActionResult Register(UserModel model)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
        using (MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext())
        {
          db.User.Add(model);
          db.SaveChanges();
        }
     }
}
```

I got the error that Invalid Column Name **ConfirmPassword**

So how to solve that  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark the column you don't want to persist to database with **[NotMapped]** attribute.

Other approach as described by **ForeverDebugging**

More detail from ["Hide" column from database, but not View in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723340/hide-column-from-database-but-not-view-in-entity-framework)